# Retrieve data from 'getDocuments' query from Firestore retrieve's empty array

Tags: arrays, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am retrieving data from my Firestore database using a 'getDocuments' query, however I am retrieving an empty array. Through debugging, I have used a `print(snapshot?.documents)` and found an empty array returned. Can someone help as to why I am returning an empty array?

getNotifications function:

```
    public func getNotifications(
    completion: @escaping ([IGNotification]) -> Void
) {
    guard let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username") else {
        completion([])
        return
    }
    let ref = firestoreDatabase.collection("users").document(username).collection("notifications")
    ref.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
        guard let notifications = snapshot?.documents.compactMap({
            IGNotification(with: $0.data())
        }),
        error == nil else {
            completion([])
            return
        }
        completion(notifications)
    }
}
```

Firestore data:

[Screenshot of Firestore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mO9UX.jpg)

Comment: This is Swift -- not SwiftUI. Have you determined if the `error` has a value in it? Have you tried printing it? Are you sure that the `username` is valid?

Comment: @jnpdx There doesn’t seem to be an error that is thrown. Everything seems to be working, just returning an empty array. And yes, I have verified that the username is valid.

Comment: Show us the array that you want to get.

Comment: @Alex Mamo I would like to get the following array: ["notificationType": 3, "identifer": 911_667_1633745168.9810839, "username": joebiden, "dateString": Oct 8, 2021 at 10:06 PM, "isFollowing": 0, "profilePictureUrl": https://iosacademy.io/assets/images/brand/icon.jpg]